# In electrophoresis of amino acids and dipeptides, how can I rationalize the observed mobilities?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, biochemistry

[image]

For part b(i) why is the spot tyrosine? I know tyrosine has an overall -2 charge while phenylalanine has an overall -1 charge. However, phenylalanine has a smaller Mr so shouldn't it travel faster? Also, I don't understand (ii)... why are they close?

Comment: So you figured out that the mobility depends on charge and on size. Make a table of the three species and their charge and size, and see if you can predict which travels the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

| Species | Charge at pH 12 | relative size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dipeptide | -2 | Large |
| Tyrosine | -2 | Small |
| Phenylalanine | -1 | Small |